# Sub numerotation for sub-definition

Tags: numbering, newtheoremstyle

I'm trying to make subdefinition nested inside another definition that use a sub-counter, like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{théorème}{0pt}{20pt}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}
{\thmnumber{ #2} \thmname{#1} \textit{\thmnote{---  #3 }}}
\tcbset{barrenoire/.style={
  boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,sharp corners,enhanced,borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black},interior hidden
  }
}

\theoremstyle{théorème}

\newtheorem{Thm}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{Defi}[Thm]{Définition}

\tcolorboxenvironment{Thm}{barrenoire}
\tcolorboxenvironment{Defi}{barrenoire}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Defi}[1. A]
        A is B and C  
        \begin{Defi}[1.1 B]
            B is this   
        \end{Defi}
        \begin{Defi}[1.2 C]
        C is that
        \end{Defi}
    \end{Defi}
\end{document}
```

I would like not to have to redefine another definition environment, so I'm looking for a way to check if the theorem environment is called inside another one, like measuring the nestedness level of the block when performing the numbering.

However I didn't find anything about this, any clue would be welcome!

Thank's!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the definition counter the main one, but define `Defi` so it uses one of two “inner” theorems, namely `xDefi` at the outer level and `xxDefi` at the inner level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle
  {theoreme}
  {0pt}
  {20pt}
  {}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {\newline}
  {\thmnumber{#2 }\thmname{#1}\thmnote{ --- \textit{#3}}}
\tcbset{
  barrenoire/.style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    enhanced,
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black},
    interior hidden,
  },
}

\theoremstyle{theoreme}

\newtheorem{xDefi}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{Thm}[xDefi]{Théorème}
\newtheorem{xxDefi}{Définition}[xDefi]
\tcolorboxenvironment{Thm}{barrenoire}
\tcolorboxenvironment{xDefi}{barrenoire}
\tcolorboxenvironment{xxDefi}{barrenoire}

\newcounter{defidepth}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Defi}
 {%
  \addtocounter{defidepth}{1}%
  \ifnum\value{defidepth}=1 
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\begin{xDefi}}{\begin{xxDefi}}%
 }
 {%
  \ifnum\value{defidepth}=1
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\end{xDefi}}{\end{xxDefi}}%
  \addtocounter{defidepth}{-1}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{Defi}
  A is B and C  

  \begin{Defi}
    B is this   
  \end{Defi}

  \begin{Defi}[What's this?]
    C is that
  \end{Defi}
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

Note the fixes to the header part. I'd avoid special characters in the theorem style name.

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, I'm not sure how it works, but it works! :) it's beautiful!